# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 Identity

Tags: asp.net

Estoy realizando una aplicación en ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC, en el cual estoy usando Identity para la autenticacion de usuarios, tengo una clase llamada Carpeta el cual tiene una relación con ApplicationUser este deriba de IdentityUser, la relación es la siguiente Una Carpeta puede pertenecer a un Usuario y un Usuario puede tener muchas carpetas al crear una carpeta registra todo bien pero cuando quiero editar dicha carpeta el primer error que tengo es el Edit de Get donde el id=1 pero cuando llega al Edit del Post ese mismo id=0 donde no acctualiza y me redirecciona a una pagina en blanco, luego el otro error es que cuando quiero editar la carpeta y este tiene una relacion con Departamento, Provincia, Municipio me recuperar sus valores pero no asi con Usuarios.

```
// GET: Carpetass/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {        
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var carpeta = await _context.Carpetas.FindAsync(id);

        ViewData["DepartamentoId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departamentos, "DepartamentoId", "Nombre");

        var fullNames = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();// Select(u => new { UserID = u.Id, FullName = u.Nombres + " " + u.Apellidos }).ToList();

        //var fullNames = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();

        **ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(await _context.Users.ToListAsync(), "Id", "FullName");**
        //ViewData["Id"] = _context.Users.Select(u => u.FullName).ToList();


        ViewData["ProvinciaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Provincias, "ProvinciaId", "Nombre");
        ViewData["MunicipioId"] = new SelectList(_context.Municipios, "MunicipioId", "Nombre");
        ViewData["UbicacionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Ubicaciones, "UbicacionId", "Nombre");

        //ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "FullName", resolucion.Id);
        //ViewData["UsersId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users.ToList(), "Id", "FullName", carpeta.Id);
        //ViewData["UsersId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users.ToList(), "Id", "FullName");


        if (carpeta == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(carpeta);            
    }

    // POST: Carpetass/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CarpetaId,IDCarpeta,AgrupacionSocial,Cuerpos,Fojas,Poligono,Id,DepartamentoId,ProvinciaId,MunicipioId,UbicacionId")] Carpeta carpeta)
    {
        if (id != carpeta.CarpetaId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(carpeta);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CarpetasExists(carpeta.CarpetaId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(carpeta);
    }
```

Segun pruebas el problema esta en esta linea de codigo en los dos casos.

ViewData["Id"] = new SelectList(await _context.Users.ToListAsync(), "Id", "FullName");

Primero que no agarra el Id del usuario y segundo que cambia el ida 0 en el post.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shJZD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG6OJ.png)

Answer (score -1):

te incluyo la respuesta que te dí en otro foro.

> "Renombra tanto el campo Id de Carpeta a digamos UserId y el ViewBag
>   lo pones como UserId? Cambia también la vista. Lo digo por no
>   confundir Id con id. A veces este ejercicio de Renombrar las cosas
>   ayuda a resolver este tipo de errores"

[Enlace foro MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/3a03e179-30db-446a-9d57-c9aafbfd5ad2/aspnet-core-mvc?forum=vcses)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/129924)

Comment: Hola, @J.Castro la respuesta iba entrecomillada comentando lo que dice el enlace. Si vas al sitio del enlace puedes comprobar que es la misma que ya Le di en el foro de MSDN. Inclusive acabo de editar mi respuesta para usar el markdown de comentario.